# Sum-if function: the value from one column and have the function sum the cells x places to the right/left of the original column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like help trying to figure out how to sumif a value from one column and then sum all the values to the left of the column.

For example, if column B has a value of 1 then sum all the cells one space to the left of column B that have a 1 in column B.

I tried using VLookup or index/match but could not get the formulas to work. I have attached an image below which might make it clearer.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMIF(B2:B14,1,A2:A14)`

So the breakdown of this formula is: `SUMIF(range,criteria,[sum range])`. The first range, is the range that you will check against the criteria that you set (if you wanted to have a cell to change what you are summing, replace `1` with that cell instead) the `[sum range]` is simply the range that you want to be added up but this will only add the rows where the `range,criteria` are true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `-1` in the `OFFSET` is for 1 column to the left.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B18=1)*OFFSET(B2:B18,0,-1))
```